# Data insert into mysql db table using PDO - Doesn't Insert Data

Tags: php, mysql, insert, pdo

I'm 'Connected to database'.  There is no data in the table, and $result doesn't echo anything.  Even though I'm 'Connected to database', the error is as follows:

```
SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected
```

I've read the relevant postings, with no luck.

```
<?php
include("/directory outside of html/db.php");

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;database=$database", $username, $password);
    /*** echo a message saying we have connected ***/
    echo 'Connected to database';
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
//try to insert data
$fname = 'BOB';
$lname = 'JONES';
$email = 'me@mymail.com';
$phone = '410-310-3456';
$resident = TRUE;
$age = '25=30';
$zip = '23456';
$result = FALSE;

  $stmt = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO volunteers
  (
   lname,
   fname,
   email,
  )

VALUES
  (
    :lname,
    :fname,
    :email,
  )');

 $result = $stmt->execute(array(
    ':lname' => $lname,
    ':fname' => $fname,
    ':email' => $email,
  ));

echo $result;   

//catch any errors from try()
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Echo `"mysql:host=$host;database=$database"` before you call `new PDO`

Answer (score 3):

Use `dbname=` instead of `database=` , like this:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
```

Alternatively, you can select later a different database with `USE`, like this:

```
$dbh->query("use newdatabase");
```

Comment: Excellent - did the trick.  I also had to remove the commas after email. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, as you seem new to StackOverflow, remember to accept the answer (check mark below the score number) so both of us get rewarded points ;-) .